# I want to iterate my set of button clicks in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am pretty new to python, I am trying to build a code which automatically retweet a tweet having a particular twitter handle(basically my keyword). I am able to click the first tweet, but not able to iterate it to other tweets. Below is my code which does the first retweet.

```
retweet_icon = openBrowser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.ProfileTweet-actionButton.js-actionButton.js-actionRetweet')
retweet_icon.click()
retweet_btn = openBrowser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.EdgeButton.EdgeButton--primary.retweet-action')
retweet_btn.click()
```

I basically want these two actions to be in loop, I tried putting `click()` in for loop while using `find_elements_by_css_selector` for its variable, but I am getting `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible"` error.

Below is the code of the button, I want to loop.

```
 <button class="ProfileTweet-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionRetweet" data-modal="ProfileTweet-retweet" 
  type="button" aria-describedby="profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-aria-1021252475133628416">
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In selenium, you can use the method `find_elements_by_css_selector` to return an iterable of selected elemenets rather than `find_element_by_css_selector` which returns just the first element.

So you code should be

```
buttons = openBrowser.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.EdgeButton.EdgeButton--primary.retweet-action')
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

Comment: Hi Tobey, Thanks, I was able to complete 1 iteration of loop, but for next iteration, it gives error, it seems it couldn't find the location of the button anymore and gives below error. selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible. Here is the code, basically I have second button after first gets clicked, it will click on the second button. a = 0
retweet_icons = openBrowser.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.ProfileTweet-actionButton.js-actionButton.js-actionRetweet')
for button in retweet_icons:
    a += 1
    print(a)
    button.click()
    retweet_b

Comment: While 2nd iteration when print returns 2, the next click button line will fail with "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible" error. Basically I am trying to auto retweet a tweeter handle, is there any other way I can achieve this. But still not getting why it doesn't find that button for next iteration. am I missing something here, or is there any other approach to do this.  Thanks